# Google Chrome 66 how to autoplay silent video jumbotron

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I use a video as a background animation on a website header. The video as no sound, it's part of the "design" and is not an "annoying noisy advertising".

Is there a way to autoplay silent videos in Chrome 66 ?

Comment: According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), muted autoplay is always allowed.  Mute your silent video and it should auto-play.

Comment: Oh.  I'll submit it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), muted autoplay is always allowed.

Mute your silent video and it should auto-play.

```
<video muted autoplay>...</video>
```